# Она притаилась, ждала – не раздастся ли стук в окно.

Tags: синтаксис

Стараюсь определить синтаксическую роль выделенного фрагмента и затрудняюсь:

> Она притаилась, ждала – **не раздастся ли стук в окно**.

Если я не ошибаюсь, если бы стоял союз "пока", можно было бы назвать его придаточным изъяснительным (ждала что? пока не раздастся стук в окно) Верно? Если нет союза, значит это не придаточное, верно? Что это в таком случае?

Спасибо!

Comment: Придаточное — понятие, относящееся к СПП, а здес БСП.

Comment: Второе предложение дополняет первое (ждала чего?). По теории здесь надо бы двоеточие поставить.

Comment: @М_Г: Aаа, вижу мою ошибку! спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

**Она притаилась, ждала – не раздастся ли стук в окно.**

Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, частица ЛИ в роли союза. **Тире как авторский знак,** обозначает увеличенную паузу.

По Розенталю  тире ставится **для интонационного отделения** главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. В данном случае интонационное деление показывает, что придаточная часть относится к двум однородным сказуемым.

Сравнить: **Не знаю, придет ли он**. Здесь ставится запятая.

Comment: А вот такое понимание (не уверен до конца). Знать (что?) придет ли, раздастся ли — это СПП, понятно, но ждать (чего?) придет ли — нет согласования. Тут скорее ждала и думала: придет ли.  Ли - усилительная.

Comment: Здесь ЛИ - вопросительная частица в роли союза, без нее не обойтись (поэтому она вопросительная, а не усилительная). Думаю, придет ли - это классическое СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, опорное слово со значением мысли. Жду (чего?), придет ли - это СПП с приместоименным  придаточным изъяснительным (вмещающие СПП). Здесь другие опорные слова (занят, интересуюсь и т.д.) более широкой тематики, но при этом они тоже требуют раскрытия содержания, то есть изъяснения.